# Unicode issue with csv and PySpark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, unicode, encoding

I have a PySpark dataframe with unicode characters like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": "somestring\u0001bla"}])
```

resulting in:
[image: Pyspark screenshot]

I want to eliminate this, either through reading or writing a new csv file. I have tried different options:

```
option("encoding", "UTF-8")
option("nullValue", "\u0001")
option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
```

and reading with with various encoding options, but nothing works. Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: What's wrong? What do you expect?

Comment: @JosefZ The issue begin when, after additional manipulation and calculation, I try to save this to json/parquet and import it into the database. In that case, the ingestion fails since the database cannot read those unicode characters. 
The simplest solution in my use case is to eliminate those unicode characters (e.g. to transform them to blank values) when reading initial .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to eliminate those characters,

`df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": "somestring\u0001bla"}])`
`df.show()`

Cant show that special character while pasting as a text here. attached as a image."https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Nh0.png"

```
|  a|  b|             c|
+---+---+--------------+
|  0|  1|somestringbla|
+---+---+--------------+
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
spark.sql("select regexp_replace(c,'\u0001','' ) from data").show()
+----------------------+
|regexp_replace(c, , )|
+----------------------+
|         somestringbla|
+----------------------+
```